# Dataframe index / filtering between two dates

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

In python, I have a dataframe with date column, from here I get the df indexes up to a specific date.

I am looking to have a 'betweeen date A and date B' as the filter, in the second test idx rather than just go with a date as follows (in other words I am taking a smaller subset for initial testing rather than say a huge set of data)

```
train_idx = np.array(df.Date < '2016-01-01')
test_idx = np.array(df.Date >= '2016-01-01')
```

Below is what I have so far and the error

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data.csv', parse_dates=[1])

train_idx = np.array(df.Date < '2016-01-01')
test_idx = np.array(df.Date >= '2016-01-01' and df.Date <='2016-03-01')
```

Returns the following
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `and` with `&` as follows:

```
(df.Date >= '2016-01-01') & (df.Date <= '2016-03-01')
```

The operator `&` operates element-wise, while your `and` attempts to combine both series as if they were individual booleans. The truth value is ambiguous means that it does not really make sense to coerce a series to either `True` or `False`.